# Variance regarding to the exponential of uniform distribution

Tags: variance, simulation, uniform-distribution

If X has a uniform distribution of [0,1], and f(x) = e^X and g(x)=2^X.

I generated 1000 values for X and applied to both two functions.

And I calculated the variance after the transformation. The result shows that 2^X has a smaller variance.

Why is this happening, isn't 2 larger than e, where does the variance come from?

The code is:

```
N <- 1000
X <- runif(N,0,1)
phi <- 2^X
var(phi)
theta <- exp(X)
var(theta)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $2$ is not [larger than $e$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29).

The constant, $e$, the base of the natural logarithm, is about 2.718.

You may already know that $e^x$ is given by the series $1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+x^4/4!+....$.

When $x=1$ that's $1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+... > 2$

Or just type `e^1` into google.

$\text{Var}(2^x) = \text{Var}(e^{x\ln 2}) \approx \text{Var}(e^{0.693 x}) $

Comment: By the way, when calculating the variance of non-linear function (i.e. e^x), how do we do that with formulas and properties of variance?

Comment: There are a number of possibilities to find $\text{Var}(g(X))$. I'll mention a few: You can find the distribution of $Y=g(X)$ and then find its variance from the definition of the variance of a random variable ($\text{Var}(Y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (y-\mu_Y)^2 dF_Y$). You can use the law of the unconscious statistician. With $\exp(X)$, you might be able to use a neat trick with the MGF of $X$ to find the variance. Besides a variety of such approaches, there are also approximations, such as via Taylor series. If you want details of these, you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: For example, I want to get $Var(\sum_{i=1}^ne^X)$ where X is Uniform(0,1), then I could just expand it -> use independence collapse to n same terms, and then take out n, and then use $E(e^{2x}-E(e^x)^2$ to get it right? Since I have an exact expression for the variance of $e^X$, so I don't need any approximations.

Comment: Correct, if you know how to evaluate $E(e^{x})$ and $E(e^{2x})$, you'd be done.